# Tell Powershell to wait for foreach to finish writing to txt file

Tags: powershell, foreach, batch-processing, synchronous, streamwriter

I have a .ps1 script that takes some of our internal SQL data and syncs it to a Google API.

It does this by running a foreach against our data, using logic to generate the API commands, and writing those commands to a text file via System.IO.StreamWriter. Then the API processor runs a batch job on the file.

The issue I'm having is that the batch job portion appears to be firing before the foreach has finished writing to the file, which makes the whole script fail.

**Here's a simplified version of my code:**

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "C:\GAM\uploads\stream\gamBatch$today.txt";

## Loop csv and generate Google OU path
Write-Host "Generating location strings, OU paths, and update commands..."

Import-CSV "C:\uploads\Upload$today.csv" | ForEach-Object {

  ## Define fancy vars here
  ## Do fancy logic here

  ## Stream command list to log file
  $line = "update $deviceId assetid $Barcode location $location ou $ouPath";
  $stream.WriteLine($line);
};

## Trim top line of batch file (Removes header line)
(Get-Content "C:\uploads\stream\Batch$today.txt" | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content "C:\uploads\stream\Batch$today.txt";

## Close Stream instance and bulk run commands
Write-Host "Running batch command..."

$stream.WriteLine("commit-batch");
$stream.close();

apiBatch "C:\uploads\stream\Batch$today.txt";
```

This generates this error in my logs:

```
PS>TerminatingError(Set-Content): "The process cannot access the file 
'C:\uploads\stream\Batch2020-05-14.txt' because it is being used by another process."
```

**How can I make Powershell wait for the txt file to finish being written before firing the batch command?**

Comment: Why not just _skip_ adding the first line the file in the first place?

Comment: Its a csv file, the first line are the headers which are needed for the logic I didn't include. Not entirely necessary to remove it, but cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to write the first line to the file, only to then remove it again immediately after (and having to rewrite the rest of the file).

If you're not doing anything meaningful with it inside the `ForEach-Object` loop, skip it immediately:

```bsh
Import-CSV "C:\uploads\Upload$today.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    # ...
    $stream.WriteLine($line)
}
```

If you need to inspect the first line inside the `ForEach-Object` body, make sure you skip calling `WriteLine()` on the first iteration:

```bsh
$first = $true
Import-CSV "C:\uploads\Upload$today.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    # ...
    if($first){
        $first = $false
    }
    else{
        $stream.WriteLine($line)
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, close the `StreamWriter` before re-writing the file with `Set-Content`, and then either use `Add-Content`, or a new stream writer to write the last line:

```bsh
Import-CSV "C:\uploads\Upload$today.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    # ...
    $stream.WriteLine($line)
}

# dispose of the current writer (will close the file stream)
$stream.Dispose()

... | Set-Content "C:\uploads\stream\Batch$today.txt"

# open a new writer and append the last string
$stream = (Get-Item "C:\uploads\stream\Batch$today.txt").AppendText()
$stream.WriteLine("commit-batch")

# or use `Add-Content`
"commit-batch" | Add-Content "C:\uploads\stream\Batch$today.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware Set-Content rewrites the file. Between that and the Skip-Object parameter before the foreach, I think I have what I need.